# Как использовать substring с конца?

Tags: java

У меня есть строка и надо вывести последние 2 значения. Как это можно сделать?

Я только новичок, еще даже "молоко на губах не отсохло".
Заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: 2 значения — это 2 символа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При условии, что в строке есть хотя бы 2 символа.

```
String res = s.substring(s.length() - 2);
```

Comment: спасибо большое